# Problems fIltering hash from href link and selecting it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**Example:**
http://jsfiddle.net/dfcyb/

I have these two vars

```
var inview = '#' + $("#container > .section > h1:in-viewport:first").parent().attr('id');
var $link = $('#menu a').filter('a[hash=' + inview + ']');
```

**inview** checks to see if a particular section is in the viewport and then using the **$link** var to add a class. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Inview is working fine but:

```
$link.parent().addClass('selected');
```

does nothing. I'm not really sure what I have wrong here or how to go about debugging since console.log($link) isn't helpful. I'm not sure if filter is being used right here?

Comment: `a[hash=` should be `a[href=`.

Comment: in the fiddle, inview returns "#undefined", maybe your fiddle needs to be more like the code you are trying to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a[hash=` should be `a[href$=`

Where `$=` means ends with.

Replace:

```
... $('#menu a').filter('a[hash=' + inview + ']');
```

With:

```
... $('#menu a[href$="' + inview + '"]');
```

Source: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/

Comment: @Tom Glad I could help. Accept when possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of issues with your jsFiddle.

First off there is no `:in-viewport` selector.  You'd need to use a plugin (like [this one](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/viewport)) to to that.

Second, `$("#container > .section > h1")`.  In your example, there are no `<h1>` tags.

Third, `<a>` tags don't have a `hash` attribute, it should be `a[href='']`.

Fourth, `$link` is the `<a>` tag, but in your CSS, the `selected` class should be on the `<li>`.

Here's an updated example: http://jsfiddle.net/dfcyb/1/

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
$("#container > .section > h1.in-viewport:first")
```

instead of:

```
$("#container > .section > h1:in-viewport:first")
```

That is where the #undefined is coming from, that and you don't have any H1 tags in your example code on jsfiddle.